# The base of the intersection of 2 vector spaces

Tags: vectors

What is the best way to find a base of the intersection of 2 vector spaces?
I have tried an equation that on the one side a linear combination of the base of the first vector space and on the other, the linear combination of the other one.
Is that the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I rephrase this?

Given a basis $b_1, \ldots, b_k$ of a subspace $U$ of a vector space $V$, and a basis
$c_1, \ldots, c_n$ of a subspace $W$ of $V$, how can we find a basis of $S = U \cap W$?

In the ase where $V = \mathbb R^n$, any basis can be written with coordinate vectors; alternatively, you can pick a basis $v_1, \ldots , v_p$ of $V$ and write each of the $b_i$ and $c_j$ in terms of the $v$s. In either case, I'm going to assume that the $b$s and $c$s are coordinate vectors. A vector is in $S$ exactly when it's in both $U$ and $W$, i.e.., when you can find coefficients $f_i$ and $g_i$ with 
$$
f_1 b_1 + \ldots + f_k b_k = g_1 c_1 + \ldots + g_n c_n.
$$
You can rewrite this as
$$
f_1 b_1 + \ldots + f_k b_k - g_1 c_1 - \ldots - g_n c_n = 0
$$
or, in matrix form, you can form a matrix $M$ with columns $f_1, \ldots, f_k, -g_1, \ldots, -g_n$,  and try to solve
$$
Mx = 0
$$
where $x$ is a column vector of $n+k$ components with entries $f_1, \ldots, f_k, g_1, \ldots, g_n$.

Using whatever algorithm you like to find a basis of the kernel of $M$ will give you a basis of the vector space $W$.